# Splunk query to extract fields from log data

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

My Splunk log some thing like `[user name] [traceid] ldap authentication { “status” : “success” , “username”: “123”} MULTIEXCEPTION some text….`

I am trying out for Splunk query that gives result in tabular format..  any query suggestions?

```
Status  username 
Success 123
Fail     234
```

Comment: Use [rex](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/9.1.1/SearchReference/Rex) command to extract values.

Answer (score 0):

As @PM77-1 wrote, use the `rex` command to extract fields from events.  Then use the (surprise!) `table` command to put the results in tabular format.

````
index=foo
``` Extract the status field ```
``` Triple escapes are needed because of multiple layers of processing ```
| rex "status\\\"\s*:\s*\\\"(?<status>[^\\\"]+)"
``` Extract the username field using a separate command for order-independence ```
| rex "username\\\"\s*:\s*\\\"(?<username>[^\\\"]+)"
| table status username
````